# A version of Brower's fixed point theorem for contractible sets?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, compactness, geometric-topology, fixed-point-theorems

[Brouwer's fixed point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer_fixed-point_theorem) states that a continuous map $f:B^n\to B^n$ ($B^n\subset\Bbb R^n$ being the $n$-dimensional ball) has a fixed point. It is clear that we can replace $B^n$ with a space $X$ homeomorphic to the ball.

> **Question:** Is there a version of this fixed point theorem that only requires $X$ to be compact and contractible? Do we need more, e.g. locally contractible or something like this? I am happy to assume that $X\subset \Bbb R^n$ for some finite $n\ge 1$.

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2682984/fixed-point-theorems-convexity-contractibility) question has a note about a contractible space for which the fixed point theorem does not hold, but it is unclear to me whether the counterexample stands if $X$ is required to be a subset of a *finite-dimensional* Euclidean space.

Comment: Yes, I just understood what you meant.  I should have read the other question before commenting. Sure, a lot of compact contractible subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$ are in fact just homeomorphic to the sphere…  or perhaps the statement should still hold if $K \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a smooth contractible manifold of dimension $n$ with connected boundary…

Comment: @Mindlack I wonder though whether this is more general: is every such manifold homeomorphic to a ball?

Comment: The Lefschetz fixed point theorem guarantees the existence of a fixed point if $X$ is triangulable and contractible (and in fact more generally than just contractible). Is triangulable good enough for you?

Comment: [Similar MathOverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/59796/17064)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $X$ is triangulable, then the Lefschetz Fixed Point Theorem can be used. If $X$ is contractible, then its rational homology $H_q(X; \mathbb{Q})$ is $\mathbb{Q}$ when $q=0$, zero otherwise, and any map $f: X \to X$ will induce an isomorphism (the identity, in fact) on $H_0$. Therefore the Lefschetz number will be 1: in degree 0, $f_*$ is represented by the $1 \times 1$ matrix $[1]$ and hence has trace 1, and in all other degrees, $f_*=0$ and so has trace 0.

Since the Lefschetz number is nonzero, then $f$ will have a fixed point, and $f: X \to X$ was an arbitrary map. In the setting where $X$ is triangulable, this generalizes the Brouwer fixed point theorem, because you don't need to know that it is contractible, just that its rational homology looks like that of a contractible space. For example, if its integral homology is $\mathbb{Z}$ in degree 0 and finite in all positive degrees, then the same argument works. Even dimensional real projective space $\mathbb{R}P^{2n}$ is a standard example: any self map of $\mathbb{R}P^{2n}$ will have a fixed point.

Answer (score 9):

There are contractible compacta without the fixed point property. In fact,

> **Theorem ([Kinoshita](https://eudml.org/doc/213332))**: There is a contractible compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ which does not posses the fixed-point property. $\square$

In a positive direction, here is a result which generalises John Palmieri's answer and follows directly from the Brouwer fixed point theorem. The idea hinges on the following observation.

> If $Y$ is a space with the fixed-point property, and $X\subseteq Y$ is a retract of $Y$, then $X$ has the fixed-point property.

To leverage this we have:

> Any compact CW complex $X$ embeds in $D^n$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$. If $X$ is contractible, then it is a retract of $D^n$.

In fact every locally-finite CW complex of dimension $n$ embeds in $\mathbb{R}^{2n+1}$ as a neighbourhood retract (see Fritsch, Piccinini, *Cellular Structures in Topology* Th.1.5.15). Of course every compact CW complex is finite-dimensional, and has bounded image under the previous embedding. That a finite complex should be a retract of any disc in which it embeds is a consequence of Paul's answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3111988/is-a-closed-embedding-of-cw-complexes-a-cofibration).

Now, in light of the previous two observations we use Brouwer's fixed point theorem to conclude the following.

> Every compact CW complex (triangulable or not) which is contractible has the fixed-point propety. $\square$

Of course the full machinery is more powerful, and has application outside the realm of CW complexes.

> Every finite-dimensional compact metric space which is both contractible and locally contractible has the fixed-point property.

The argument is as before. Show that the spaces in question embed in some disc as a retract and quote the Brouwer fixed point theorem.